# 'Connect-PnPOnline' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

Currently I'm using [this](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.UI.Responsive#requirements) git hub article.

I'm using this for SharePoint online. So I have installed **SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline.msi** from [this](https://github.com/sharepoint/pnp-powershell/releases/tag/2.10.1612.0).

After that I have try to run script **Enable-SPResponsiveUI.ps1**. But It will show

error:

**The term 'Connect-PnPOnline' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

Comment: What is you PowerShell version? Check by running `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.17929
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16384
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2

Comment: Just Found solution here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199756/how-should-i-update-the-office-sharepoint-pnp-powershell-commands
By running Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline 
Thanks

Comment: It works fine but show another error like "Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate : Value cannot be null"

Comment: `Value cannot be null` that's another story...something wrong with pnp provisioning.. Ideally stacktrace might help a log

Comment: I have resolve that too, some minor changes in xml file.

Comment: @Akshay, that Install-Module pointed me in the right direction, too. Can you put that in as an answer to your post so it is easier for the next person to see what worked?

Answer (score 13):

There are multiple ways to install the PnP cmdlets. As you discovered in [your comment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/204052/connect-pnponline-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet#comment217500_204052) the tools can be installed *"...By running `Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline`"* which is what Microsoft recommends<sup>1</sup>. It's possible the other option you tried with the `.msi` file failed because there was an open instance of PowerShell that needed restarting?

## Installation options

### 1. Install from [PowerShell Gallery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps#powershell-gallery)

> If you main OS is Windows 10, or if you have [PowerShellGet](https://github.com/powershell/powershellget) installed, you can run the following commands to install the PowerShell cmdlets:
>
> - SharePoint Online: `Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline`
> - SharePoint 2016: `Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2016`
> - SharePoint 2013: `Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShell2013`

### 2. Install from [setup files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps#setup-files)

> You can download setup files from the [releases](https://github.com/sharepoint/pnp-powershell/releases) section of the PnP PowerShell repository. These files will up be updated on a monthly basis. Run the install and restart any open instances of PowerShell to use the cmdlets.

### 3. Using an [installation script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps#installation-script)

> This is an alternative for installation on machines that have at least PowerShell v3 installed. You can find the version of PowerShell by opening PowerShell and running $PSVersionTable.PSVersion. The value for Major should be above 3.
>
> To install the cmdlets you can run the below command which will install PowerShell Package Management and then install the PowerShell Modules from the PowerShell Gallery.
>
> ```
> Invoke-Expression (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sharepoint/PnP-PowerShell/master/Samples/Modules.Install/Install-SharePointPnPPowerShell.ps1')
> ```

## Footnotes

1. [Microsoft Docs, PnP PowerShell overview, Installation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps#installation) *"We recommend, where possible, to install them from the PowerShell Gallery."*

Comment: If you don't have local admin access to the computer you can add "-Scope CurrentUser" to get it installed as well. 

`Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Scope CurrentUser`

Comment: Just as an update, the Online library in this answer is legacy.

Instead, run:
Install-Module -Name PnP.PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

The PnPOnline package is installed to the user profile only by default. So if you are logged into the server with your account, and install PnPonline, then run the PowerShell window under the SharePoint farm account, you will get the above error. You have to log in as the farm account and install the PnPOnline package under that account.